# inserting char arrays in buttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, button, awt

I'm trying to put the alphabet in different buttons, but I cant make it work. My code looks like this:

```
char[] Letter = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'
                    ,'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'
                    ,'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
Button[] But;
for (int i = 0; i <= 26; ++i) {
    But = new Button(Letter[i]);
    this.add(But[i], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: I removed a lot of unnecessary noise in your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Makenshi please 1) change `Button` to the `JButton`, 2) all of your JComponents must be started with char `"J"`, 3) don't use `AWT Components`, 4) and to avoid mixing `AWT Components` with Swing JComponents` , 5) otherwise nobody to guarentee correct output to the Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Its convention in Java to name variables starting with a lower case letter.

```
char[] letters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'
        ,'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'
        ,'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
Button[] buttons = new Button[26];

for(int i = 0;i< 26;++i){
    buttons[i] = new Button(Character.toString(letters[i])); //need to convert char to String first
    this.add(buttons[i],BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: ic i will take that in account but im still getting the error "Cannot find symbol,symbol: constructor Button(char) location:class java.awt.Button it seems i cant use chars in buttons or something

Comment: Just edited my answer to fix the problem you are having. The constructor for Button needs a String but I was passing a char by mistake. I have commented the line it was happening at. Therefore technically you cannot use primitive char's to create buttons with they need to be converted to String.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] letters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
for(char c : letters) add(new JButton(new String(c)));
```

Comment: Seems nice but could you do it with normal button please im not suppossed to use swing library right now :S

Comment: @Makenshi Just replace `JButton` with `Button`

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted this

```
But[i] = new Button(Letter[i]);
```

instead of this

```
But = new Button(Letter[i]);
```

Comment: oh yeah sry forgot to put that but yeah it still doesnt work it says that But might not have been initialized :S

Comment: That is because "Button[] But" should be "Button[] But = new Button[26]".

Comment: yeah fixed that but it seems like the error is because i cant use chars in buttons or something any idea what can i do? is there a cast or something?